# maven: skipping a plugin goal when running locally

Tags: maven

I have a maven project with a plugin configured that takes care of creating a docker image and pushing it to a docker repo.

But I want push part not to execute when I run maven build locally.

What is best practise for achieving it?

Comment: To which phase is the docker plugin bound?

Comment: It's bound to deploy phase.

Comment: In this case you can build locally via `mvn verify` instead of `mvn deploy` and it will not run the build of the image...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property which you can use in your plugin configuration and set the desired value in your `mvn` command:

```
    <properties>
        <pluginskip>false</pluginskip>
    </properties>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>...</groupId>
        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        <configuration>
             <skip>${pluginskip}</skip>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

This allows you to run: `mvn ... -Dpluginskip=true`

Comment: But this would skip whole plugin, isn't?I want to skip one of the goals only.

Comment: Aha indeed. Was a bit too eager.